# Sci-fi short story about an astronaut adrift in space and a teapot

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, space

The story I am referring to was a part of an collection of horror/sci fi stories by Indian authors and had a yellow sandy cover. I read it in 2011/2012.

The story in question had an unnamed female astronaut adrift alone in her spaceship after all her crewmates die in a freak accident/due to malicious force. She dreams of their deaths every night in vivid nightmares describing in detail their bulging eyes and silent screams as they die in suffering from oxygen deprivation.

Russell's teapot makes an appearance. In her loneliness she starts treating the teapot as sentient. The teapot seems significant since she is refusing to accept the burden of proof of proving something malicious happening and instead takes all the blame for herself.

One day, another ship (perhaps a mining ship) makes contact with the astronaut's ship. She joyfully replies on the radio and establishes contact. Mid conversation the malicious force transmits itself over to the other ship and she is treated to the death rattle of the other ship's crew.

She then resumes her conversation with the teapot, now truly alone yet again.

Comment: "Russell's teapot makes an appearance." Can you explain more about what this means?